# Returning values from an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I had this code working for an Array...then re-read the instructions to find it specifically calls for an array LIST. I cannot seem to convert the methods beneath to be acceptable for the ArrayList...Please assist in how I need to change the verbiage...See below for a sample method:

```
public static int returnMin(ArrayList intArr) 
{  //Return the Min Value.
int minValue = intArr.get(0);
for(int i=1;i < intArr.size(); i = i+1){
    if(intArr.get(i) < minValue)
    { minValue = intArr.get(i);
    }
}   
return minValue; 
}
```

Comment: It would help if you posted the error message

Comment: It has to do with incompatible types-- Object cannot be converted to int
 int minValue = intArr.get(0);
                          ^
 bad operand types for binary operator '<'
  if(intArr.get(i) < minValue)

Comment: @Archaimot you will want to use typed collections.  ArrayList<Integer> for example.

Comment: Has to do with bad types. I'm having trouble with changing it over to work with Arraylist....even though the Arraylist has always referenced integers it doesn't like anything that tries to say it's an integer (int minValue = intArr.get(0)  or intArr.get(i) < minValue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your method declaration, change:
`...(ArrayList intArr) {` **to** `...(ArrayList<Integer> intArr) {`.
 This will make the elements in `intArr` `Integer`s and not an `Object`s. To learn more about generics in java, look at [The Java™ Tutorials on Generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html).

Answer (score 2):

try casting the objects retrieved as in

```
int minValue = (Integer) intArr.get(0);
```

and again with

```
if((Integer)intArr.get(i) > minValue)
```

Comment: Or use generics so you don't have to cast.  
     returnMin(ArrayList<Integer> intArr)

Comment: @scarywombat using your suggestion I have it down to only having an error on the comparison --- if(intArr.get(i) > minValue)

Comment: Updated my answer, but as @km1 mentions it would really be better if you used generics

Answer (score 0):

As your ArrayList work only with int values, you should specify the type of your ArrayList in you method parameter:

`public static int returnMin(ArrayList<Integer> intArr) {
     .
     .
     .
 }`

**Why to specify the type?**

Well if you does not specify, your ArrayList will accept any value (String, Integers and any other) so when you use arrayList.get(0) you don't know what type is in that position and that is why in your example you have to cast it to Integer. Always when you are working with only one type, you should specify the type of your List to avoid this.

**Generics tutorial:**
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/why.html